# Polygons have holes after pgr_pointsAsPolygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, pgrouting, isochrone

I calculate a 500m Isochrones with pgr_drivingDistance and after that use pgr_pointsAsPolygon to create the Isochrones out of the resulting nodes.

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_pointsAsPolygon('SELECT id,x,y FROM Calc_nodes')
```

Sadly in some case the Dijkstra algorithm create holes in the resulting poylgons. I know the reason for this is the nature of the network and how the algorithm works.

I just need function to check if there are holes and then get rid of them. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: pgr_pointsAsPolygon functional also has an optional 3rd parameter, the alpha value, which may affect, if you have wholes or not: http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_pointsAsPolygon.html#pgr-points-as-polygon You could play with the value and see, if it returns better results for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_ExteriorRing(<pgr_polygon_geometry>)) AS geom
FROM <your_query>
```

to process all polygons, or

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN ST_NRings(<pgr_polygon_geometry>) > 1
         THEN ST_MakePolygon(ST_ExteriorRing(<pgr_polygon_geometry>))
         ELSE <pgr_polygon_geom>
       END AS geom
FROM <your_query>
```

to only process those with an interior ring.